# SSMS 18.4 Crashes when we attempt to script entire database

Tags: scripting, ssms

We just started noticing this. It used to work, and now it doesn't. The crash happens on all of our computers. We right click on a database, select Script Database..., choose to script the entire database and SSMS crashes. No information in the Event Logs. We've found that if we script all tables, it works. If we also script all stored procedures and functions, it crashes. All of our databases are in Azure. Haven't tried local DBs. Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved changing scripting options. Try going to Tools/Options.../SQL Server Object Explorer/Scripting then scroll down to "Version options". These options work for my Azure Databases: "Match script settings to source"=False and the other two options set to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database Edition" and "Microsoft Azure SQL Database"

Comment: Thank you for your post. I made the changes you suggested and, while SSMS no longer crashes, I get "Script Generation Failed. Click on Help for Know Solutions." Of course the help is no help. It's a generic page about how to run the wizard. It seems there no longer a place to report bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late to answer but it might help someone;
I had the same issue recently, upgraded to the latest version 18.12.1 and it now works fine;
Check [Download SSMS 18.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16)
Click on "Free Download for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.12.1"
and run the installed file "SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe" as an administrator and follow the wizard.